# ccsm/window rules/size rules: can window be maximized vertically?

Tags: unity, ccsm

I'd like to place any new emacs windows maximized vertically on the left half of the screen. The window rules plugin of Compiz aims to solve these kind of problems,
but I don't see an option to do this there.

Just to restate:

I don't want do drag the window to the left until it snaps and maximizes
every time I open a new window.

I want this to be done automatically on per-application basis.

Comment: I think there is no such option yet.

Answer (score 0):

Combine "Window Rules" plugin with "Place Windows" plugin. First one (tab "Size rules") will set the desired size, the second one (tab "Fixed Window Placement") will set the desired position of the windows with `title=^emacs`.

Comment: I tried that one as well. It doesn't offer to maximize a window vertically.

Comment: Right you are. "Place Windows" cannot resize windows. But "Window Rules" can. Just calculate the desired window size and set it there. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Let me state this again: I'm interested /only/ in maximize vertically option. I've tried what you described and it doesn't work. It makes the window either too small or too big, never the full desktop height.

Comment: The closest thing in ccsm to what I want is the Grid plugin. Its "Put Left" function is exactly what I need. But I don't want to use the shortcut each time. I want it automatic.

Comment: I've tested everything once again. Well, my advice works correctly for graphical windows. emacs is a bit specific. If you turn on "Resize Info" plugin, you'll see, that emacs shows _symbols_ count on resize, not _pixels_. Workaround: with turned on "Resize Info" plugin open some graphical (i.e. non terminal) window, for example gedit, resize it as you wish your emacs window must be and get its _pixel_ size. Then set this size in "Window Rules" plugin for your emacs window. I got it working as desired.

Comment: Still won't work because of what you said: it counts the size in chars not pixels. So at 1080 pixels, I get 51 char height, which doesn't fill the display completely. And of course the next size of 52 chars is too big for the diplay.

Comment: It's a pity, as I've got another screen geometry and on my screen this window fits rather good. BTW, middle button click on Maximize button maximizes window vertically. Alas, I cannot help you anymore.

Comment: Thanks anyway. Btw this rule applies to all windows generated by emacs, so I got a Yes/No messagebox on half my screen.